# css orderd list with colored brackets

Tags: css, html-lists

how can i set a different color for brackets around the incrementor in an ordered list. Or how can set another color just for the incrementor?
for details please visit jsfidlle link. https://jsfiddle.net/bnk2saqe/

```
ol { list-style: none; padding-left: 2em; text-indent: -2em;}

.simple-footnotes-list li::first-letter {
  color: blue;
}

ol .simple-footnotes-list li::nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}

.simple-footnotes-list li:before {
  content: "[" counter(section, decimal) "]";
  color:#FF4500;
  font-weight: bold; 
}

li { counter-increment: section;}
```

Comment: Use javascript. You can have an array of colors. Use .each() to iterate and everytime you set the color you pick a different color from the array

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
.simple-footnotes-list li:before {
    content: "[" counter(section, decimal) "]";
    font-weight: bold; 
}
.simple-footnotes-list li:nth-child(1):before {
    color:#FF4500;
}
.simple-footnotes-list li:nth-child(2):before {
    color:#45FF00;
}
```

You could also use nth-child(xn) for cycling colors.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Oceanity/f5oreyeb/)